# Power BI "Bind to parameter" not visble for Calendar based table

Tags: powerbi

I have created Calendar based table by following the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters Here is the expression for the table:

```
EndDateTable = CALENDAR (DATE(2016,1,1), DATE(2016,12,31))
```

Now I am trying to bind the `Date` field of this table to the parameter, but there no `Bind to parameter` select-options is available in the `Advanced` category. I have header about limitations and that this `Bind to parameter` is available for certain tables and queries only. But I have done everything as suggested in this tutorial and this tutorial suggest the `Bind to parameter` exactly to this type of table. And, nonetheless, this `Bind to parameter` is not available. How to get at available?

Uhh, what a program Power BI is!

*Additional information* I enabled 'File - Options and Settings - Options - Global - Preview Features - Dynamic M Query parameters', but still there is no `Bind to parameter`. Well, there is ODBC data source (with M query code) on my model pane as separate query, but, well, it is just the presence of it. I am trying to bind the Date field from the Calender table - as suggested by the article. Without success.

*Additional information* There is mentioned the limitation about 'Direct Query' only. Well, yes, I have the presence of non-Direct Query component on the Model view (it is ODBC query which has no Direct Query mode), but I am trying to bind the field for the custom Calendar table which is generated according to the mentioned description. Mybe `Bind to parameter` is not available due to the presence of this non-Direct-Query Query. Very strange...

Answer (score 1):

"Maybe Bind to parameter is not available due to the presence of this non-Direct-Query Query. " - this true. After I removed the "Calendar = Calendar(date(2021, 1, 1),TODAY())", the Bind to parameter option appeared under advanced. Of course, "File - Options and Settings - Options - Global - Preview Features - Dynamic M Query parameters" must be enabled as well.

I found that after I've removed the table (Calendar = Calendar(date(2021, 1, 1),TODAY())), the Bind to parameter option appeared under advanced. Thereafter, I can put back the calendar table with the Bind to parameter option remaining visible.

[image]